# Storing in an ENV the outcome of a git command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm having a hard time storing the output of a git command into an environment variable in my Dockerfile.

How can I save in `TAG` the outcome of `git describe --tags`?

Thanks and have a good 1.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood after some researching it's not possible for now to define dynamic ENV in docker file. But you can do it on container running:

```
docker run --env TAG="$(git describe --tags)" your-image
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I wasn't aware of ARG. However, I get `Missing ':' in substitution: TAG=${git` when I try to build the image.

Comment: @macsig try `TAG=$(git describe --tags 2>&1)` (`()` instead of `{}`)

Comment: `Step 13 : ARG TAG=$(git describe --tags 2>&1)
ARG requires exactly one argument definition`  Thanks

Comment: @macsig I fixed my answer

Comment: @Cortwave Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I need to do it in my Dockerfile so I have switched from storing the tag in an ENV variable to storing the tag in a file.